# How use iis url rewrite extension

Tags: node.js, iis, web-config, iis-8

I'm using node js inside IIS 8.0, 
I run successfully in localhost, but when I try to push into server, I get 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
then I found out it must use url-rewrite extension so I can bypass the permission.
but I got 500 - internal server error.

this is sample of my web.config

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>

  <handlers>
   <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
   </handlers>

   <rewrite>
    <rules>
     <rule name="myapp">
      <match url="/*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
     </rule>
    </rules>
   </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I can't event load the index, which is only `hello world text`

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that the URL Rewrite module is installed? http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite